# How to use a dynamic variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to create something like :

```
var term = new Terminal();
```

each time I click on a button. I have found that we can create dynamic variable like this in JavaScript:

```
window["term_" + _idContainer] = new Terminal({
                cursorBlink: true,
});
```

But I'm not sure about this because I can only use the last one that I create.

So someone could tell me if it really create dynamic var and if they aren't overwritten each time we create one.

Comment: could you use an array?

Comment: where does `_idContainer` come from?

Comment: why not use an object or an array?

Comment: @DanielA.White it comes from a value of a container, you can replace it by a random number to understand

Comment: @NinaScholz how could I create dynamically some var with an array ? If you have an example I'll like to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an object, without polluting the global space, like

```
var collection = Object.create(null); // empty object without prototypes

// use
collection["term_" + _idContainer] = new Terminal({ cursorBlink: true });
```

Comment: and then to use it I would have to do `collection["term_" + _idContainer].doSomething()` right ?

Comment: right, that would the access to the instance of `Terminal`.

Comment: Well, that depends on where exactly this code executed. Just declaring a var still adds it onto `window`, unless you're within a function.

Comment: It seems working, I'll keep trying with this method instead of mine. Thank you for the help

Comment: @CobusKruger, it is a difference to generate one global variable, or a namespace or just hundreds.

Comment: @NinaScholz Absolutely, you're right. But you said "without polluting the global space", which could be interpreted to say you're not adding anything to the global space at all. I simply clarified that you're still adding at least one. Your answer remains valid.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript objects are effectively dictionary-style objects. Therefore, you can add a property to any object in these two ways:

```
myobj.newProp = 'I am new!';
myobj['newProp2'] = 'So am I';
```

And therefore, yes, what you are doing is creating a sequence of new properties on the `window` object. There is no reason the one would overwrite the other, unless you neglected to increment `_idContainer`.

I should add that adding variables to the `window` object is not a popular thing to do and you could be adding many with this mechanism. Perhaps better would be to just add one, and expand it as needed:

```
window.termList = {};
// Then, in a loop or whatever
window.termList[_idContainer] = new Terminal({cursorBlink: true});
```